# Use `onclick` with context menu child items?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have this code in my `manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "description": "test of Context Menus",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus"
  ],
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

And this is my `background.js` file:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  var parent = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "TEST", "contexts":["all"], "id": "parent"});  
  var child1 = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Test2", "parentId": "parent", "id": "child1", "onclick": showURL, "contexts": ["all"]});
});
```

and this is my `showURL` function (in the `background.js` file) **Note: This is at the very top of the document**:

```
function showURL() {
alert(document.URL);
}
```

But running this makes the `child1` item disappear. Why is this?

***Note: When I remove `"onclick": showURL,` then it shows the `child1` item.***

So, I know something is wrong with the `onclick`, but I don't know what!

Please help me, I can't figure out what is wrong with the code! I think the syntax is correct according to Google's API documentation, so what's wrong??

This was supposed to be a learning project - learn a simple part of the Chrome Extension API - and already, I have a problem! I know programming is a 'problematic' endeavour but, come on! Someone must know a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you have read [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus), you haven't read them attentively enough:

> (optional) onclick:
>
> A function that will be called back when the menu item is clicked. **Event pages cannot use this; instead, they should register a listener for chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.**

Your `"persistent": false` in the manifest defines an Event page. You should [restructure your code to fit](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages), and use the event-based click handling for `contextMenus`.

P.S.: Please note that event pages are conceptually harder to program than persistent background pages. If it's a learning experience, you can try switching away from event pages.

Comment: WOW! Thanks. I feel really stupid now! I've got a noob question though: *What's the difference between an *event page* and a *background page**? If you could try to answer *simply*, I'd be grateful!

Comment: Basically, an event page is destroyed every time it's idle for more than a second or so, but Chrome remembers that it needs to be "spun up" again for certain events. This means one needs to be careful with event listeners and cannot keep local JS state.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a long shot but...

Are you defining the showURL function AFTER you define the chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener method? Or BEFORE ?

If you reference something that is not (yet) defined, then it is possible that "var child1 = chrome.contextMenus.create" code is not completing properly.

Try moving the showURL definition prior to the chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(...) line.

(It's been a while, I'm rusty, and may be barking up the wrong tree on this).

Comment: I am defining it before and it doesn't work. Sorry, I should have said in the question!